# ArrayList in new line

Tags: java

I have a file containing many lines each line looks like 1,2,3,4. Now i have add every line to Arraylist and print it, my output looks like this

1

2

3

4

5

6

What i want is to write the same data of file in new file as it was at previous file. what can i do. My Bufferwriter code is.

```
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/koshis/Downloads/Sample_Input_Reverse_Elements_output.tx  t", true);
 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
  bufferedWriter.write(Arraylist);
  bufferedWriter.newLine();
  bufferedWriter.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over list elements and write them as separate lines:

```
for(String e : list) {
   bufferedWriter.write(e);
   bufferedWriter.newLine();
}
```

Comment: @koshishkharel here you should not iterate items by considering them as String type. The items may be of any type which we dont have any proper information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator it= list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     bufferedWriter.write(it.next());
     bufferedWriter.newLine();
}
```